# Managing Users and Roles from the website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm working on a website in ASP.NET/C# and I'd like to make it possible to manage Users and Roles from the admin section in the website.

Are there any reusable, probably open-source, web application that I can include in the website to do this? I know that the membership API exists and can do this but I'm looking for more than an API, such as some controls or webforms, it's a common need so I thought may be there's something to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching again and again I was able to find what I was looking for, a web app pages that manages Users and Roles, implemented with and without AJAX, you can see it in action at http://livedemos.peterkellner.net/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t32yf0a9(VS.80).aspx

SUMMARY: During this walkthrough, you will learn how to:

1. Establish roles for an application.
2. Assign users to roles.
3. Create rules (permissions) that
   selectively grant or deny access to
   pages for different rules.

   Programmatically d
4. Determine whether a
   user is in a particular role and
   which roles the current user is in.

Comment: I already know about the API, I'm looking for a page to manage users and roles.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Spring.NET does not have any Acegi Security module but I could be wrong.

This might be what you are looking for: http://sourceforge.net/projects/aceginet/

Answer (score 0):

A CMS such as DotNetNuke will have this...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#ASP.NET